# Pgsql configuration file in Maven + web application

Tags: postgresql, maven

I wanted to connect my JSF web application to PostgreSQL database. There is example for ActiveJDBC connection through Maven in GitHub. Maven plugin is like:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
<artifactId>db-migrator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${activejdbc.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <configFile>
${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/database.properties
    </configFile>
    <environments>${environments}</environments>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And, my database.properties file is as follows:

```
development.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
development.username=postgres
development.password=****
development.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first
```

When I run console java, it works perfectly, but when I try to run Tomcat server and web application, server gives me error:

> Caused by: org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Could not find configuration in a property file for environment: development. Are you sure you have a database.properties file configured?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are configuring the Migration plugin. The database management is described here: 
http://javalite.io/database_connection_management

Take some time to read an understand the docs: 
http://javalite.io/documentation :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer